# How to pass Static member function of a c++ Class to template and invoke the function

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have a C++ program where I am able to call non static functions by calling via object.
Calling non-static function:

```
#include <iostream>
class ClassF {
public:
    void enumerateF() {
        std::cout << "f1\n";
        std::cout << "f2\n";
    }
};

class ClassG {
public:
    void enumerateG() {
        std::cout << "g1\n";
        std::cout << "g2\n";
    }
};

template<typename F, typename FUNC>
void do_work(FUNC g)
{
    F f;
    (f.*g)();
}

int main()
{
    do_work<ClassF >(&ClassF::enumerateF);
    do_work<ClassG >(&ClassG::enumerateG);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives output:

> f1
>
> f2
>
> g1
>
> g2

How to call static function:

```
#include <iostream>
class ClassF {
public:
    static void enumerateF() {
        std::cout << "f1\n";
        std::cout << "f2\n";
    }
};

class ClassG {
public:
    static void enumerateG() {
        std::cout << "g1\n";
        std::cout << "g2\n";
    }
};

template<typename F, typename FUNC>
void do_work(FUNC g)
{
    (F::*g)();
}

int main()
{
    do_work<ClassF >(&ClassF::enumerateF);
    do_work<ClassG >(&ClassG::enumerateG);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives error:

> Error C2760 syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ')'

But I don’t know how to call static functions by passing the name of the static function as parameter to a template. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke the static member function via the function poitner `g` directly as

```
g();
```

Note that `&ClassF::enumerateF` constructs a function pointer with type `void(*)()`, which has become unrelated with the class type `ClassF`. That means, you don't need the template parameter `F` as the class type, which has been specified when specifying the static member function. e.g.

```
template<typename FUNC>
void do_work(FUNC g)
{
    g();
}
```

and then

```
do_work(&ClassF::enumerateF);
do_work(&ClassG::enumerateG);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sSCHTztFkHfKNtC7)

Comment: As an appendix, example usage `do_work<void(*)() >(&ClassF::enumerateF);`

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution to the sample code is working perfectly. However in my real example, the class restricts creation of default constructor and it is not working when I apply the same solution there. I am however very grateful for your solution

Comment: Is there any way to make the following work: `template<typename F, typename FUNC>
void do_work(FUNC g)
{
    F::g();
}`

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' For static member function, you don't need an instance of class, so whether it's DefaultConstructible or not shouldn't matter..

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' No. As I stated in my answer, the funtion pointer's type is unrelated to the class type, then you can't qualify it like `F::g();`. Could you just write it as `g();`? i.e. Just omit the template parameter `F`, even I don't think it's a good design..

Comment: I have doubt with the call to the template, let me update the question.

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' For your updated question, see [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xKfz9g6C31anZfa6). Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves the problem in the sample code. perhaps the problem is in some other part of the code. Thank you for helping me. :)